# YUI Resize -- handles not showing

Tags: resize, yui

I am really new to YUI and have been struggling with this for days now..

I have this piece of code where detailsPanel is HTMLDivElement

var resizeDetails = new YAHOO.util.Resize(detailsPanel,
{
    handles: ['t'],
    maxHeight: 150

});

When I examine this in Firebug there is no resize handle on top. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, but what can it be? Are there some requirements that have to be fulfilled in order for the handles to show up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know with YUI the documentation pages with examples are not always complete (or assume advanced knowledge of previous pages/topics).  If you didn't already try this: do a view source on their sample page and check your example against it to see if you can spot the differences:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/resize/simple_resize_clean.html

We have solved numerous YUI issues ourselves this way.  Good luck!